# How to use a sql table-valued parameter to filter results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that uses a [table-valued parameter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) to filter imported names.  We get a list of names imported and need to return a list of names that either do not exist in the database or they've already received a message of a specific type.

The part I'm having difficult with is how to create the joins.  A left outer join with a IS NULL check would work for a single table check but I'm not sure about two tables.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

I'm using MS SQL 2012. Tables with their columns:

```
Recipients: 
id | name 

SendResults:
id | recipientid | type
```

Tes

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_RecipientsSendCheck]
(
     @Type int 
    ,@RecipientsImports dbo.RecipientsImport READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT i.Name FROM @RecipientsImports i

    LEFT JOIN Recipients r
    ON i.Name = r.Name

    LEFT JOIN SendResults s
    ON s.RecipientId = r.id 

    WHERE r.Name IS NULL OR Type <> @Type

END
```

User defined table type

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[RecipientsImport] AS TABLE(
    [Name] [nchar](10) NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
create procedure [dbo].[usp_RecipientsSendCheck]
(
    @Type int,
    @RecipientsImports dbo.RecipientsImport READONLY
)
as
begin
    select i.Name
    from @RecipientsImports as i
        left outer join Recipients as r on r.Name = i.Name
        left outer join SendResults as s on s.RecipientId = r.id and s.[Type] = @Type
    where
        r.Name is null or
        s.id is not null
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  For some reason your changes are excluding names that are in the Recipients table and have a SendResults record with a different Type. Any idea why?